# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable: Calender module

Tags: python

I am using Calendar function in python for the first time this is my code:

```
import calendar

print ("The calender of year 2018 is : ")
print (calendar.calendar(2018,2,1,6))
print ("The starting day number in calendar is : ",end="")
print (calendar.firstweekday())
```

I am getting the followng output

```
The calender of year 2018 is : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AAKASH PATEL/Desktop/calendar.py", line 5, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "C:/Users/AAKASH PATEL/Desktop\calendar.py", line 10, in <module>
    print (calendar.calendar(2018,2,1,6))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

How can i solve this

Comment: Look closely at your traceback. You imported your own script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your script name from `calendar.py` to `calendarScript.py`

```
"C:/Users/AAKASH PATEL/Desktop/calendar.py"
```

to

```
"C:/Users/AAKASH PATEL/Desktop/calendarScript.py",
```

**Note:** Do not name your script the same name as a module.

Comment: *calendarScript*: not very *Python*ic (*PEP8*).

Comment: @CristiFati...its just an example :)

Answer (score 2):

You named your script `calendar.py`, so *it is that file that is imported*. You can see this in the traceback:

```
  File "C:/Users/AAKASH PATEL/Desktop/calendar.py", line 5, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "C:/Users/AAKASH PATEL/Desktop\calendar.py", line 10, in <module>
    print (calendar.calendar(2018,2,1,6))
```

So `import calendar` imported `calendar.py`, which now has an attribute `calendar`, which is your script.

Rename your script to not mask the built-in library; for example, `calendar_demo.py` would be fine. Once you do, it works perfectly, on my system, it outputs:

```
The calender of year 2018 is :
                                  2018

      January                   February                   March
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7                1  2  3  4                1  2  3  4
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14       5  6  7  8  9 10 11       5  6  7  8  9 10 11
15 16 17 18 19 20 21      12 13 14 15 16 17 18      12 13 14 15 16 17 18
22 23 24 25 26 27 28      19 20 21 22 23 24 25      19 20 21 22 23 24 25
29 30 31                  26 27 28                  26 27 28 29 30 31

       April                      May                       June
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                   1          1  2  3  4  5  6                   1  2  3
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8       7  8  9 10 11 12 13       4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15      14 15 16 17 18 19 20      11 12 13 14 15 16 17
16 17 18 19 20 21 22      21 22 23 24 25 26 27      18 19 20 21 22 23 24
23 24 25 26 27 28 29      28 29 30 31               25 26 27 28 29 30
30

        July                     August                  September
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                   1             1  2  3  4  5                      1  2
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8       6  7  8  9 10 11 12       3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15      13 14 15 16 17 18 19      10 11 12 13 14 15 16
16 17 18 19 20 21 22      20 21 22 23 24 25 26      17 18 19 20 21 22 23
23 24 25 26 27 28 29      27 28 29 30 31            24 25 26 27 28 29 30
30 31

      October                   November                  December
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7                1  2  3  4                      1  2
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14       5  6  7  8  9 10 11       3  4  5  6  7  8  9
15 16 17 18 19 20 21      12 13 14 15 16 17 18      10 11 12 13 14 15 16
22 23 24 25 26 27 28      19 20 21 22 23 24 25      17 18 19 20 21 22 23
29 30 31                  26 27 28 29 30            24 25 26 27 28 29 30
                                                    31

The starting day number in calendar is : 0
```

Note that `calendar.calendar(2018)` would suffice; the defaults for the next three arguments (`w` for the column width, `l` for lines per week, and `c` for the spacing between month columns) are 2, 1 and 6 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

When copying your code and executing it, it works perfectly fine! But I see that it seems your script, where you have that code is called calendar.py! Python then thinks this is what you want to import! So rename your script to something else!